# SQL Check datetime value constraint while creating a table

Tags: sql-server, datetime, constraints, ddl

I would like to ask whether there is any possible way to do a check constraint on a `datetime` column, making sure that the column is either in the month of November or May.

```
Create Table TestDate (
.....
.....
date datetime not null default '14/11/2012'
...
...
constraint dateCheck check *date must be either November or May*
```

Thank you so much for your help!

Edit: Adding on to the question,

Would it be possible to set the default value for the date column to '14 November 2012' instead of '14/11/2012'? I understand that it is using date time data type, and can't be changed unless it is change to a string (char/varchar) data type?

Comment: You've tagged this for both MySQL and SQL Server.  Which of the two databases are you using?  The syntax will likely be different.

Comment: Ops sorry, it's sql-server

Comment: @Daniel: You already have use NOT NULL constraint for column, now the default values will not be considered as you are not allowed to skip this column on INSERT.

Comment: @PareshJ Technically, it make sense, but is it possible to set the default value to '14 November 2012' instead of '14/11/2012'? I will be copying values from another table to this table and will not be filling up this column.

Comment: @PareshJ So it's possible to set the default value to '14 November 2012' directly. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`month`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187813.aspx) function to extract the month part of the date:

```
CREATE TABLE TestDate (
    date datetime not null default '14/11/2012'
    constraint dateCheck check (MONTH(date) IN (5, 11))
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can add the constraint on month part of date column. Check the below example:

```
Create table TestTable
(
   from_date DAtetime

   constraint checkdates check (DATEPART(mm, from_date) = 11 OR DATEPART(mm, from_date) = 5)
);
```

Above script will restrict the insert into **from_date** column if *datepart* does not contains month November or May.

Yes, You can use Default value as '14 November 2012'. Check this version:

```
Create table TestTable
(

   from_date DAtetime default ('14 November 2012') 

   constraint checkdates check (DATEPART(mm, from_date) = 11 OR DATEPART(mm, from_date) = 5)
);
```

And, try this insert statement to check the default value:

```
Insert into TestTable DEFAULT values
```

Comment: Thank you. Just another question, would it be possible to set the default value for the date column to '14 November 2012' instead of '14/11/2012'? I understand that it is using the datetime data type.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the [`datepart` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) in a `check` constraint

```
create table testDate (
  dt datetime not null default '14/11/2012'
 );

alter table testDate 
  add constraint chk_month
    check( datepart( month, dt ) in (5,11));
```

You can see an example of this in [this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0a5a7/1)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Trigger (before insert, and before update) to handle your requirements.  the following MSDN link might help you http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx

Comment: Which query are you referring to for the trigger? The check constraint or setting the default value?